# How to create a form that queries objects in a Model and display the query results in a new page?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a hobby website (Airbnb clone) where on the index page there is a form that accepts a city and a property type (Apartment, Office, Restaurant, etc).

I am using Django as my backend.

Hosted: https://directoffices.azurewebsites.net/ (May take some time to load ** No CDN config)

The pages are index and listings where the index is the landing page that consists of the search form and listings that have the properties listed.

I've built a form (forms.py) :

```
class SearchPropertyForm(ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['city'].required = False
    self.fields['city'].empty_label = 'Where do you want to go?'
    self.fields['city'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'chosen-select-no-single'})

    self.fields['property_type'].required = False
    self.fields['property_type'].empty_label = 'Any Type'
    self.fields['property_type'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'chosen-select-no-single'})
    

class Meta:
    model = Listing
    fields = ['city', 'property_type']
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
searchForm = SearchPropertyForm()

CONTEXT = {
        'searchForm': searchForm
    }

if request.method == "GET":
    searchForm = SearchPropertyForm(request.GET)
    if searchForm.is_valid():
        location = searchForm.cleaned_data.get('city')
        property_type = searchForm.cleaned_data.get('property_type')
        listings = Listing.objects.filter(
            city=location, property_type=property_type)


        return render(request, 'core/listings.html', {'listings' : listings})
    else:
        searchForm.errors.as_data()
else:
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', CONTEXT)
```

HTML:

```
<form class="main-search-form" method="GET" action="/listings/">
    ** CONTENTS AND FIELDS **
</form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from core import views as coreViews
from users import views as userViews
from properties import views as propertyViews

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', coreViews.index, name="index"),
    path('listing/', coreViews.listing, name='listing'),
    path('contact/', coreViews.contact, name='contact'),
    path('privacy-policy/', coreViews.privacyPolicy, name='privacyPolicy'),
    path('terms-and-conditions/', coreViews.terms, name='terms'),

    path('login/', userViews.loginPage, name='loginPage'),
    path('logout/', userViews.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path('register/', userViews.registerPage, name='registerPage'),

    path('property/', include('properties.urls', namespace='property')),

    path('submit-property/', propertyViews.submitProperty, name='submit_property'),
    path('sample-property/', propertyViews.sampleProperty, name='sample_property'),

    path('user/<str:user_id>/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am not sure whether this is the correct way of doing it and once the listing page is up, the index page always redirects to the listing page and there is no way to go back.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your URLs, possibly anproblem there.

Comment: I've gone on the demo site and I am able to navigate back to the index after the listings, so not clear on the issue - it appears the site is not passing search parameters though - is that correct?